# Debug website from PC - Problems with Samsung devices

Tags: browser, android, debug

some users of our website are experiencing some problems with the layout of our website. Users affected have: Samsung S5, Samsung ACE 4 and Samsung Grand Neo. They all use the default android browser.

I don't have a Samsung device to test the situation. I've used Google Chrome tools which helped me to view the website as Samsung Galaxy S3, S4, Note II and Note 3, but I haven't been able to replicate the bug.

What can I do to emulate the situation on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools), and use the Android Device Manager (ADM) to emulate an actual Android device and the Android browser on your computer.